# UI Dialog window - How to not display dialog until content is loaded?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I've been experimenting with using a UI Dialog window to display an existing form  (page with the form and no layout).  I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way but it seems to work fine minus a couple of pieces of bad behavior.   This is the behavior right now:

1. The dialog window with no conent opens (very small/empty)
2. About a half second later the content loads and the window expands insantly (looks bad visually)
3. Even though the window width expands when the content is loaded, the title bar does not adjust to the new width and remains very small width wise.  Although if resizeable is set to 'true' the title will expand.  It's just not responding with a width adjustment when the content from the hidden div is loaded.

How could I go about not displaying the dialog until the content is finished loading into the dialog, and how could I force the dialog title to width adjust right after the content is finished loading?

```
<A HREF="javascript:newItem('foo')">CREATE NEW FOO ITEM<A>

<script type="text/javascript">
    newItem= function(type) {
      $("#form_load").load(
          '/items/new', {item_type: type}).dialog({
                modal:true,
                draggable: true,
                resizable: false,
                width:'auto',
                height:'auto',
                title: 'Some title',
                position: [150, 150]
          });
    };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to call the dialog after the content is loading.
You can do this by using $.load's callback method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    newItem = function(type) {
        $("#form_load").hide().load(
            '/items/new',
            {item_type: type},
            function (data) {
                $(this).dialog({
                    modal     : true,
                    draggable : true,
                    resizable : false,
                    width     : 'auto',
                    height    : 'auto',
                    title     : 'Some title',
                    position  : [100, 100]
                });
            }
        });            
    }
</script>
```

You may also want to include a hide/show toggle so the #form_load container isn't displayed until the content is loaded.

See jQuery's $.load docs here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

**UPDATE:** Added .hide() so content isn't shown until dialog is created.

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work for me though.   The problem doesn't seem to be coming from the load event.   It looks like after the div is loaded with the form, the dialog window opens and then there's a split second delay while the content from the div is being replicated in the dialog (and after the content makes it's way to the dialog, the dialog auto-resizes to the content but the title bar does not).

Comment: OK I didn't notice this at all but the behavior is only happening in IE7.  It's not happening in IE8 or Firefox.    It has something to do with .ui-helper-clearfix (or really something not being fixed by .ui-helper-clearfix)

Comment: Do you have an example of this online?

Comment: no sorry...   the clearfix css line in IE7 is actually keeping the line from being verry narrow.   There's actually two of those lines as well.   Looks like:   http://img28.imageshack.us/i/58058957.png/

Comment: now that I know what the problem is - think I'll check your answer off since you showed my how to write the function correctly and I know exactly what the problem is now to be more specific.

Comment: @Reno, Thanks! I'm glad you figured it out.